# c#, udpClient.Receive, An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, udpclient

Ok so i have a program that queries game servers from a datatable and adds them to a listview.

If one of the servers from the datatable go offline i receive this error:

```
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The specific line of code throwing this exception is:

```
Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
```

My method for querying servers:

```
private void QueryServer(IPAddress IP, int Port)
{
    udpClient.Connect(IP, Port);

    Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\\100 * 1024\\");

    udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);

    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IP, Port);

    Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

    string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

    if (returnData == "")
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        ProcessPacket(receiveBytes, receiveBytes.Length, RemoteIpEndPoint);
    }
}
```

I tried adding a try/catch block to ignore the exception and return from the method, but the next time my server query method is called instead of trying to query the next server it automatically catches even though the next server is online and wouldn't throw an exception if the method was using the code in the try block to query it.

Is there anyway around this?

My server query method with try/catch block:

```
private void QueryServer(IPAddress IP, int Port)
{
    try
    {
        udpClient.Connect(IP, Port);

        Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\\100 * 1024\\");

        udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);

        IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IP, Port);

        Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

        string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

        if (returnData == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            ProcessPacket(receiveBytes, receiveBytes.Length, RemoteIpEndPoint);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line throws it? The `Connect` or the `Receive`?

Comment: the Receive line.

Comment: Not that this is the issue, but setting the remote IP end point to `IPAddress.Any` and Port to `0` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ok, I have changed it to `IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IP, Port);` It was not the issue but at least it is corrected.

Comment: I believe i know why this error is occurring, one of the servers in my data table is offline/down, so i need to find a way to make sure the `QueryServer` method is not called if the server is down. i have to avoid pinging the servers as some of the servers are not pingable and have DDoS protection.